# Android Ispeech rest request with API key failed. Any idea?

Tags: android, api, text-to-speech

I have problem with the API key (I'm using Mobile Production with iSpeech SDK (free) (for Android) and REST client). I get this API key error:

```
"result=error&code=1&message=Invalid+API+key+or+key+not+provisioned+for+use+on+this+production+server.+Please+check+your+key+settings+at%3a+http%3a%2f%2fwww.ispeech.org%2f"
```

But when I used `"developerdemokeydeveloperdemokey"` instead of my API key it works well. Could you help me, please?

In manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="org.ispeech.iSpeechFramework" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <meta-data android:name="ispeech_api_key" android:value="my_api_key" />
        <meta-data android:name="debug" android:value="false" />
```

My request url:

```
String url="http://api.ispeech.org/api/rest?apikey=my_api_key&action=convert&text=something&voice=usenglishfemale&format=mp3&frequency=44100&bitrate=128&speed=1&startpadding=1&endpadding=1";
```

Comment: I learnt. For android there is no need for request. ispeech sdk can do it without any request.